# How can I achieve consistency in timestamps when using Firestore if some of the time stamps I set from the client side and some from the server side?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

**New info at EDIT 3**

So far I've had no issues with timestamps as I've added them on the client side with simple `System.currentTimeMillis()`.
Now I am moving some of my functions to the cloud, and it seems like I can't generate a timestamp in a simple milliseconds Long like before.

Searching how to set it I found out that the method is using `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` but I am facing an issue.

Some of my objects get time stamped when the user creates them. For example, if I need to compare it to SO, when a user uploads a new question then I place the timestamp of creation and also the timestamp of last interaction as one of the fields in the question object and then save it to the server.

My problem starts when I try to edit this object from the cloud. If for example someone posts an answer to this question, I want to edit the timestamp of the last interaction and update it to the current time. But the time stamp generated by the server is in a completely different format (`Map<String, String>`) than the one I generated on the client side.

What's the right way to handle this? Is there a way to convert this `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` to a a Long before saving it to the object?
Or should I somehow generate on the client side a timestamp that fits the one generated by the server? For my understanding this isn't even possible as this timestamp is just a place holder?

Should I maybe upload the question with an empty `Map<String, String>` and have a function triggered when a new question is created, that edits the timestamp to the correct one?

Would love to know what the right approach would be as timestamps are something I'd like to have consistent as I move forward and don't want to change later.

For example, this is my Question object:

```
@Parcelize
class Question(
    val id: String,
    val title: String,
    val details: String,
    val timestamp: Long,
    val author_ID: String,
    val author_name: String,
    val author_image: String,
    val last_interaction: Long,
) : Parcelable {
    constructor() : this("", "", "", 0, "", "", "", 0)
}
```

And I would post a question like this:

```
val questionRef = db.collection("questions").document()
questionRef.set(
Question(questionRef.id,
"My title",
"My details",
System.currentTimeMillis(),
"My author Id",
"My author name",
"My author image",
System.currentTimeMillis())
)
```

But now when I want to edit this object from the cloud and update the `last_interaction` field, how can I set it in Long?

For my understanding, I can convert whatever the timestamp is into the milliseconds format when reading the data, but the problem I am facing is how to save the data in a consistent way.

**EDIT:**
This is the function I am trying to use at the cloud.

```
exports.updateLastInteraction = functions.firestore.document('communities_data/{community}/answers/{answerID}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const newAnswer = snap.data();
    if (newAnswer !== undefined) {
        const promises = [];

        //I got a few more promises here

        promises.push(db.doc('communities_data/' + context.params.community + '/questions/' + newAnswer.question_ID).update({ last_interaction: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() })
        );

        return Promise.all(promises);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
});
```

So at first the timestamp was set with just a simple Long, but now it been updated to be whatever format firebase sets it to be which is different.
So I need to check what format it is in my code every time to handle it properly?

**Edit 2:** Maybe I got this. So this format firebase saves to is a date format? So if from my code I'll convert the milliseconds to a date before saving, I should be alright and consistent? Trying to check that now.

**Edit 3:** Ok, this took me some time because I had to reset all the database and try to start all over. The first operation in which the app breaks is caused because of the user object I'm creating, which contains a timestamp.

This is my user class:

```
class UserObject {
    uid: string;
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    communities_list: Array<string>;
    lang_list: Array<string>;
    reputation: Number;
    join_date: FieldValue;
    last_activity: FieldValue;
    constructor(uid: string, first_name: string, last_name: string, communities_list: [], lang_list: ["en"], reputation: Number, join_date: FieldValue, last_activity: FieldValue) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.communities_list = communities_list;
        this.lang_list = lang_list;
        this.reputation = reputation;
        this.join_date = join_date;
        this.last_activity = last_activity;
    }
}
```

Then I have this cloud function that should create a new user whenever a new user is authenticated. This is the function:

```
exports.userCreated = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    const currentTime = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
    const newUser = new UserObject(user.uid, "Friend", "", [], ["en"], 0, currentTime, currentTime);
    return db.doc('users/' + user.uid).set(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newUser)));
});
```

The functions seemed to work, kinda. The fields of `join_date` and `last_activity` seem to be empty.

[image]

But, the real problem is that the app crashes when opening because it can't convert type HashMap to Date.

This is the class I use in my app that I try to convert the data into:

```
@Parcelize
class User(
    val uid: String,
    val first_name: String,
    val last_name: String,
    val communities_list: MutableList<String>,
    val lang_list: MutableList<String>,
    val reputation: Long,
    val join_date: Date,
    val last_activity: Date
) : Parcelable {
    constructor() : this("","", "", mutableListOf(), mutableListOf(), 0, Date(), Date())
}
```

After I saw this error, I tried to change the type for `joind_date` and `last_activity` from `Date` to `HashMap` thinking that maybe the date is the value of the hashMap?

I did that and tried to print the value of those fields, and while the app didn't crash, it indeed returned an empty value:

```
2019-07-30 16:10:55.252 24401-24401/com.myapp D/what is this timestamp: {}
```

So I am still very confused, how do I get the timestamp?

Comment: If you're dealing with true Timestamp objects, you shouldn't be seeing any maps in Firestore.  They should be saved as native timestamp type fields.  If you're seeing a map (perhaps with seconds and nanoseconds?), you've done something wrong.  You might want to edit the question to show the actual code you're dealing with rather than just a description of what's happening with it.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've added some code. I am still trying to understand how to work with these timestamps. I assumed it is `Map<String, String>` because I saw this info repeating in many answers, but maybe it's only when using the realtime database equivalent `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`? When I used the previous and tried to query by timestamp the results didn't even come in the right order. Regardless, my issue lies in the difference in formats (between the one generated by the client and the one by the server), regardless of what the format is. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't see anything in your code so far that uses FieldValue.serverTimestamp() or any date type.  What you've shown now will just write strings and numbers.  So I'm not yet clear at all on what you're actually expecting to happen.  Numbers will not automatically becomes timestamps.  It doesn't work much at all like it does with Realtime Database, which does not have a timestamp type.

Comment: I've added my cloud function. Sorry if it seems like I'm not writing everything. Trying to be concise and writing what I thought was relevant.

Comment: So what exactly is the result of those document updates?  What do your documents look like after that's done?  A screenshot might be helpful.

Comment: Ok, this took me some time because I wanted to rest everything and start over. I've added a new edit explaining in details what I've tried.

Comment: Hey Doug, did my third edit make any difference? It's been a few days now and I still haven't figured out what's the right way to go around this